# append new div and store that div into a variable

Tags: jquery, html

I will make a new row on my draw-area what's a section. I append it to the draw-area but I will receive the new tree-row in the variable row. How can I do this? In other words I'll append a new div and store that in a variable. Now I store `.draw-area` in the variable.

```
var row = $(".draw-area").append('<div class="tree-row"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this:

```
var row = $("<div class='tree-row'></div>");
$(".draw-area").append(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it:

```
var row = $(".draw-area").append('<div class="tree-row"></div>').find('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I've understood well, you mean this?

```
$(".draw-area").append('<div class="tree-row"></div>');
```

And after insert, store it on a variable:

```
var row = $(".draw-area").last();
```

Comment: I'm sorry: it was not what I will.